# More understanding about $E_u[\partial_x h(x,u)]$, $u$ is a random variable

Tags: expectation, subgradient

Consider the **subdifferential** "$\partial_x h(x,u)$", $u$ is a random variable. (Note: subdifferential is a set with the definition in subgradient method.)

How to understand $$E_u[\partial_x h(x,u)]$$ and $$\{E_u[g_u]\ \ \big| \ \ g_u\in \partial_x h(x,u)\}$$

1. $E_u$ is the expected value with respect to $u$.

Moreover, are both equal?

Comment: I can't find enough information to be sure, but from what I've gleaned from wikipedia, the subdifferential of a convex function is essentially all possible tangents to the function, and it makes sense that one might want to "average" these tangent functions at a point to produce a single linear approximation to the function at a point in situations where there might be multiple choices (e.g., if $f(x)=|x|$, there are many subdifferentials at $x=0$, but in some sense $0$ is the best value to pick for the derivative at the point).  However, without more information, I don't have a guess (cont)

Comment: ...for how one averages the options in general.  There is a probability distribution of some sort, but I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems $\{E_u[g_u]|g_u \in \partial_x h(x,u)\}$ is the definition of $E_u[\partial_x h(x,u)]$. If $h(\cdot,u)$ is a convex function, then $\partial_x E_u[h(x,u)] = E_u[\partial_x h(x,u)]$.

A good reference is Bertsekas's 1973 paper, "Stochastic Optimiation Problems with Nondifferentiable Cost Functionals"